# How to Add default date in json for copy activity in azure data factory(adf) while dynamic mapping of columns between SQL source and sink

Tags: json, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

Well dynamic column mapping in copy activity between SQL source and sink working fine.

I want to add a default value like current date in target table which not exists in source.

How can i add default value in json so that i will be able load default date in target column.

Json being used in mapping is attached:

[image]
I want to add todays date in jason which not exists in source. Which edit in jason will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add default value, I have used data flow.

I have created new column and added default value as current date.

First created a parameter.

I have used CSV file as a Source dataset. Which has 6 columns.

Schema of source dataset –

```
Id,
Region,
Country,
UnitsSold,
TestCol1,
TestCol2
```

Added new column as DefaultDateValue.

Then I created parameter “date” which has `currentDate()`.

In last step I assigned “date” parameter to DefaultDateValue column.

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "DerivedColumn2"
                }
            ],
            "script": "parameters{\n\tdate as date (currentDate())\n}\nsource(output(\n\t\tId as string,\n\t\tRegion as string,\n\t\tCountry as string,\n\t\t{Units Sold} as string,\n\t\tTestCol1 as string,\n\t\tTestCol2 as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1\nsource1 derive(DefaultDateValue = $date) ~> DerivedColumn2\nDerivedColumn2 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tinput(\n\t\tColumn_1 as string,\n\t\tColumn_2 as string,\n\t\tColumn_3 as string,\n\t\tColumn_4 as string,\n\t\tColumn_5 as string,\n\t\tColumn_6 as string\n\t),\n\tskipDuplicateMapInputs: true,\n\tskipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea How can we make column mapping of data flow dynamic?